# Keying Set Failed To Insert Any Keyframes error message?

Tags: animation

So I'm working on an animating project and I think I clicked some hidden hotkey because I'm suddenly getting the error message "Keying set failed to insert any keyframes". For some reason none of the solutions online seem to work/I can't find where people are talking about. I have deleted the keying groups among other things but nothing seems to work. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5268" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5268/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to bse. Could you please add some detail. For instance what keying set is failing, what properties it keys.  How you are using etc.

Comment: @batFINGER I'm so new to animation that I honestly have no clue what you're talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set your Keying Set (1) to Button Keying Set, but you didn't add any properties for keyframes to be added to (2). That's why when you press I no keyframes are being added. To change that, you need to get rid of the Keying Set by clicking on x sign or setting something meaningful, like LokRotScale for example.[image]

Comment: After pressing x the I menu now comes up but still gives me the error message when I try to add a keyframe. Changing to LocRotScale also gives me the same error message.

Comment: You forgot to mention, that you locked all channels. You need to go to the Dope Sheet or Graph Editor and unlock them (click on the padlock icon).

Comment: omg thanks so much I'm not sure how I was dumb enough to lock them -.-

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and the solution is simple.
Delete any value here [image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. Could you elaborate on what that does exactly and how it helps solve the issue?